# In Gitab repo Merge Requests shows "Checking pipeline status" as stuck

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

We recently updated gitlab server and we can see for some repos while creating Merge Requests we can see "Checking pipeline status" as stuck. We verified and confirmed settings for "Pipelines must succeed" is not enabled for this repo and also this repo has no .gitlab-ci.yml. On these job we had jenkins pipeline jobs as web hook. In https://gitlab.com/group/project/-/pipelines its empty.

But for other repos in which we had the same settings as above repo like it has no .gitlab-ci.yml and "Pipelines must succeed" is not enabled. Only same is it has also jenkins job as webhook. While creating Merge requests we can successfully see as "Pipeline #66437 passed for 79387d74 on geo/added-feature 25 minutes ago".  Also on these gitlab repository on CID pipelines we can see different pipelines executed and while clicking we can see its an external pipeline as [image: jenkins]

While clicking we are getting jenkins url like https://jenkins.geo.com/blue/organizations/jenkins/test-job/detail/unit-test/3013/pipeline

Can anyone please help to identify why MRs on above jobs shows "Checking pipeline status" as stuck. Also while checking logs didn't find anything relevant.